# How to install Chrome extension that is not on the Google Store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I play http://www.conquerclub.com in my free time. There is a Firefox/GreaseMonkey script for this game called BOB that also works on Chrome, but I can't get it installed on my new PC while it runs fine on my old PC.

When I try and click the Install button I get the message that extensions can only be installed from the Google Store. The script is not on the store.

How can I copy the extension to my new PC?
It isn't synchronized like the other scripts and I already tried to copy the folder to my `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` folder without result. I hate to use Firefox just for this one extension. Has someone a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

1. Download the Chrome extension and open the `.crx` file with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org).

   [image]
2. Extract the contents of the archive to a directory somewhere.
3. Open Chrome and type `chrome://extensions/` into the address bar.

   [image]
4. Check the "Developer mode" checkbox.

   [image]
5. Click "Load unpacked extension" and browse to the directory where you extracted the files.

   [image]
6. The extension should now install.

Comment: I googled a lot before making this question, and i saw this solution, but there is no .ctx file just a folder with a manifest file and a .js script

Comment: @peter: Does the `.js` file by any chance end with `.user.js`?

Comment: And importing it unpacked or trying to pack it doesn't work, manifest file niot found or incompattible..

Comment: yes, you can find it here http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/52341

Comment: @peter: Ah, then it is a UserScript and not a Chrome extension at all. You can install that by simply dragging the file on to the `chrome://extensions` page.

Comment: Instructions are here: http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

Comment: after renaming the script.js i got from my old pc to script.user.js it worket, thanks, can't understand why google makes this so difficult.